# Oracle Forms 6i SendMessage with String

Tags: oracle, delphi, plsql, sendmessage

I am converting my pascal code to PL/SQL for use with Oracle Forms 6i. My pascal code below, works perfectly.

```
program WebcamTest;
//cswi
//www.delphibasics.info
const
  WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT = 1034;
  WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME = 1084;
  WM_CAP_SAVEDIB = 1049;
  WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT = 1035;

function SendMessageA(hWnd: Integer;
                      Msg: Integer;
                      wParam: Integer;
                      lParam: Integer): Integer;
                      stdcall;
                      external 'user32.dll' name 'SendMessageA';

function capGetDriverDescriptionA(DrvIndex: Cardinal;
                                  Name: PAnsiChar;
                                  NameLen: Integer;
                                  Description: PAnsiChar;
                                  DescLen: Integer) : Boolean;
                                  stdcall;
                                  external 'avicap32.dll' name 'capGetDriverDescriptionA';

function capCreateCaptureWindowA(lpszWindowName: PAnsiChar;
                                 dwStyle: Integer;
                                 x : Integer;
                                 y : Integer;
                                 nWidth : Integer;
                                 nHeight : Integer;
                                 ParentWin: Integer;
                                 nId: Integer): Integer;
                                 stdcall;
                                 external 'avicap32.dll' name 'capCreateCaptureWindowA';

function IntToStr(i: Integer): String;
begin
  Str(i, Result);
end;

var
  WebCamId : Integer;
  CaptureWindow : Integer;
  x : Integer;
  FileName : PAnsiChar;
begin
  WebcamId := 0;
  CaptureWindow := capCreateCaptureWindowA('CaptureWindow', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  if CaptureWindow <> 0 then
  begin
    if SendMessageA(CaptureWindow, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, WebCamId, 0) = 1 then
    begin
      for x := 1 to 20 do // Take 20 photos.
      begin
        SendMessageA(CaptureWindow, WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME, 0, 0);
        FileName := PAnsiChar('C:\Test' + IntToStr(x) + '.bmp');
        SendMessageA(CaptureWindow, WM_CAP_SAVEDIB, 0, LongInt(FileName));
      end;
    end;
    SendMessageA(CaptureWindow, WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, 0, 0);
  end;
end.
```

I have successfully translated all of the apis using the ora_ffi package.

I am having trouble translating the below line from Pascal to PL/SQL (which saves the captured picture to a specified location identified by FileName).

```
SendMessageA(CaptureWindow, WM_CAP_SAVEDIB, 0, **LongInt**(FileName));
```

because I am unsure how to pass the FileName as a PLS_INTEGER (see bold for how I achieve this with pascal) which the SendMessageA definition requires. With pascal I can just cast the FileName to LongInt (does this return a pointer to the FileName? If so, I would like to emulate this casting with PL/SQL).

NOTE: The question is about how to convert **Pascal** to **PL/SQL**. The Pascal code works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is very confusing, because it contains lots of code that is not relevant. It makes it appear that you're asking a question about how to do something in Pascal, and you provided very little text to indicate otherwise. I'd suggest editing to remove the entire block of code at the top, and restrict what you include to the `SendMessageA` line with an explanation of what you're having trouble doing in PL/SQL.

Comment: @Danny, Googling around, the best I can suggest you is to make a library from your project and use your library using the `ORA_FFI` package instead of trying to make such simply looking but quite complex thing in PL/SQL.