# Saving images from the Clipboard using pure API

Tags: delphi, clipboard

I'm having trouble saving images from the clipboard using pure API.

Here is my code. It creates 20 empty bmp files. I have checked dwSize and it is correct so it seems I am retreiving the data correctly, but I am writing to a file incorrectly.

```
  program WebcamTest;
  //cswi

  uses
    Windows;

  const
    WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT = 1034;
    WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME = 1084;
    //WM_CAP_SAVEDIB = 1049;
    WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY = 1054;
    WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT = 1035;

  function SendMessageA(hWnd: Integer;
                        Msg: Integer;
                        wParam: Integer;
                        lParam: Integer): Integer;
                        stdcall;
                        external 'user32.dll' name 'SendMessageA';

  function capGetDriverDescriptionA(DrvIndex: Cardinal;
                                    Name: PAnsiChar;
                                    NameLen: Integer;
                                    Description: PAnsiChar;
                                    DescLen: Integer) : Boolean;
                                    stdcall;
                                    external 'avicap32.dll' name 'capGetDriverDescriptionA';

  function capCreateCaptureWindowA(lpszWindowName: PAnsiChar;
                                   dwStyle: Integer;
                                   x : Integer;
                                   y : Integer;
                                   nWidth : Integer;
                                   nHeight : Integer;
                                   ParentWin: Integer;
                                   nId: Integer): Integer;
                                   stdcall;
                                   external 'avicap32.dll' name 'capCreateCaptureWindowA';

  function IntToStr(i: Integer): String;
  begin
    Str(i, Result);
  end;

  var
    WebCamId : Integer;
    CaptureWindow : Integer;
    x : Integer;
    FileName : PAnsiChar;
    hData:  DWORD;
    pData:  Pointer;
    dwSize: DWORD;
    szText : AnsiString;
    FileHandle, BytesWritten : LongWord;
  begin
    WebcamId := 0;
    CaptureWindow := capCreateCaptureWindowA('CaptureWindow', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    if CaptureWindow <> 0 then
    begin
      if SendMessageA(CaptureWindow, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, WebCamId, 0) <> 1 then
      begin
        SendMessageA(CaptureWindow, WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, 0, 0);
      end
      else
      begin
        for x := 1 to 20 do // Take 20 photos.
        begin
          SendMessageA(CaptureWindow, WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME, 0, 0);
          FileName := PAnsiChar('C:\Test' + IntToStr(x) + '.bmp');
          //SendMessageA(CaptureWindow, WM_CAP_SAVEDIB, 0, LongInt(FileName));
          SendMessageA(CaptureWindow, WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY, 0, LongInt(FileName));
          if OpenClipBoard(0) then
          begin
            hData := GetClipBoardData(CF_DIB);
            if hData <> 0 then
            begin
              pData := GlobalLock(hData);
              if pData <> nil then
              begin
                dwSize := GlobalSize(hData);
                if dwSize <> 0 then
                begin
                  FileHandle := CreateFileA(FileName, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, CREATE_NEW, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN, 0);
                  WriteFile(FileHandle, pData, dwSize, BytesWritten, nil);
                  CloseHandle(FileHandle);
                end;
                GlobalUnlock(DWORD(pData));
              end;
            end;
            CloseClipBoard;
          end;
        end;
      end;
      SendMessageA(CaptureWindow, WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, 0, 0);
    end;
  end.
```

Comment: Some thoughts: 1. You aren't checking for errors in most of your API calls. 2. Please don't use magic constants when calling `CreateFile`. Don't make us work out what those constants mean. 3. You really don't want to be using `FILE_SHARE_WRITE`. 4. Did you check that the bitmaps are put in the clipboard correctly?

Comment: 5. the [`WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743896(v=vs.85).aspx) should have both parameters set to 0 (even when I don't think it would hurt it somehow, check the result of that message is a must).

Comment: 6. Why did you give up on `WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEDIB`?

Comment: @TLama 5. This is left over from my previous version where I was trying to use WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEDIB. I have checked that the image is copied by successfully pasting the capture into mspaint. 6. I worked out that I needed to pass the address of the filename in integer form to use WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEDIB, but I could not work out how to retreive the pointer of the variable holding the filename in PL/SQL. Therefore, I opted to use a different tact.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan 1,2 & 3 the constants represent GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, CREATE_ALWAYS and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN, respectively. Why should I not use FILE_SHARE_WRITE?

Comment: Because you don't want to share the file at all, and certainly not allowing others to write to it whilst you are doing so. Please fix the magic constants.

Comment: SendMessageA(CaptureWindow, WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEDIB, 0, LPARAM(PChar(FileName)));

Comment: I have added the constants you requested. I did note your answer on my previous question (thank you), however this proved difficult for me to translate into PL/SQL. I have revised my question and I will attempt to translate this method instead.

Comment: Without a delay, this approach is doomed.  With a long enough delay (between the copy and paste operations), it might work, in a laboratory setting with no other clipboard viewers running.  In real-world situations, it won't work at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a very (very!) bad idea to (ab)use the clipboard to transfer image data from a capture window just because you want to get to the data in-memory, since you're writing to a file anyway I very warmly suggest you stick with the `WM_CAP_SAVEDIB` option. (Just to give you two very good reasons: in the clipboard it's out there accessible to other processes: security!; it drops whatever was in the clipboard: inconvenient!)

But to give an answer to your question: WriteFile takes Buffer as an untyped argument, so if you pass it a pointer it takes the *value* of the pointer, not the data pointed to, unless you specify it should do so, like this (caret suffix):

```
WriteFile(FileHandle, pData^, dwSize, BytesWritten, nil);
```

Comment: +1, as a sidenote, in my view, the whole concept is a bad idea. OP wants to import Windows API functions to [`use them in PL/SQL`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12100605/960757), so in fact write this project in PL/SQL. The best would IMHO be to make own library doing this stuff and simply call it from PL/SQL.

Comment: Agreed. Unless the user intentionally placed the images onto the clipboard, the OP has no business trying to get them FROM the clipboard.  This is definitely clipboard abuse.

Comment: This works! thank you very much, I am now creating files which are no longer empty, however I cannot open them:
---------------------------
Paint
---------------------------
C:\1.bmp
Paint cannot read this file.
This is not a valid bitmap file, or its format is not currently supported.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
Any further ideas?

Comment: Please, *please* use `WM_CAP_SAVEDIB`. I'll post another alternative in a separate answer.

Comment: I really wanted to use WM_CAP_SAVEDIB, but my issue arises when I attempt to translate the code into PL/SQL. I cannot translate the cast: LongInt(FileName). Which passes a pointer to the FileName null terminated string. I cannot recreate this with PL/SQL so I tried to use the WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY method instead. Please understand.

Comment: *I cannot recreate this with PL/SQL because I cannot retreive the pointer to a VARCHAR2 typed variable

Comment: I had a quick Google, and learned a little about about PL/SQL from here: http://sqltech.cl/doc/dev2000/help/fbhelp20.htm I suggest you define a second function handle to SendMessageA, but register the last parameter as C_CHAR_PTR

Answer (score 1):

Since using the clipboard for something not in response to user interaction is so bad (*very very* bad), I'll provide another alternative to get to the grabbed frame's data. If you pass `capCreateCaptureWindow` a handle to a control of a form, after you send the `WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME` message, you can use [`BitBlt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to copy this data to a bitmap using the `Canvas.Handle` on the form and the bitmap.
An important downside to this method is that the form is required to be visible on screen.